# A letter of support for a grant from an independent practitioner

Tags: funding, recommendation-letter, projects, research-proposal

I am applying for a grant and am strengthen my proposal with letters of support. I will probably need help in a domain that I am not familiar with (i.e. Ophthalmology). A friend of mine is an independent ophthalmologist working with several health institutions. He offered to support me and write a letter of support to be submitted together with the proposal to show the funding organization that there is someone who will cover the lack of knowledge in that area.

Actually, I have never come across a letter of support written by an independent person. Would this letter look strange in my application even if it fulfils its main purposes (supporting the applicant with what he/she needs)?

Comment: Is this proposal for research or clinical work? Does the person have the same focus (research v clinical)?

Comment: The proposal is for research in CS and ophthalmology is the application domain/case study.

Comment: I can't give an answer, but I think that other things here are more important than the fact that the person is independent. That should be settled by their qualifications. But the "research" issue is more important to think about.

Comment: Are you asking for funding for some of their time? If not, are they offering time as a volunteer? Either way, how much time? Is that amount reasonable?

Comment: @BryanKrause No, he won't be a member of the project consortium. I mean no funding for him and ordinarily, the letter of support is not binding. It just demonstrates that the applicant knows what he is doing and that he/she already recognizes what is needed and even found who can help and support.

Comment: But why would this person not be on the official team? That is what is confusing about the situation.

Comment: @Dawn as mentioned already, he is an independent practitioner.